# Ruby DateTime human timezone output

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to output the timezone of a ruby DateTime object:

```
DateTime.parse('2012/05/23').strftime('%Z')
```

This outputs `"+00:00"`. According to the documentation, it should return `GMT`.

Am I doing something wrong, or have I found a bug?

Comment: Of note: I filed a bug about this: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6491. Not the response I was expecting.

Comment: I just ran into this issue and just found this post.  I need +09:00 to be JST.  I'm even fine to "tell" the object that it's JST... I just need it to return that when I ask for %Z.  Very confusing as the object & the documentation are at odds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` class does not seem to support zone data as zone names. The `Time` class however does this correctly. So either do this:

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

Time.parse('...').strftime('%Z')
```

Or if you already have your data in `DateTime` format then:

```
Time.parse(DateTime.parse('...').to_s).strftime('%Z')
```